# Is it possible to have Bamboo conditional build when other builds passed?

Tags: continuous-integration, bamboo

Let's assume I have build plans `A`, `B`, `C` and `D`. Successful `A` build triggers `B` and `C` builds in parallel. Now I want to trigger build `D` if and only if `B` and `C` passes - how can I achive that?

```
  A
 / \ // A triggers B and C (This is already implemented)
B   C
 \ / // How to trigger D if B and C are successful?
  D
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Atlassian Bamboo](https://www.atlassian.com/software/bamboo/) offers this functionality via its (otherwise fairly limited) [Conditional build triggers](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bamboo/triggering-builds-289276897.html#Triggeringbuilds-Conditionalbuildtriggers):

> You can choose to run builds of this plan only if other specified
>   plans are currently passing. Those plans must build successfully
>   before this plan will be built. See also [Setting up plan build
>   dependencies](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bamboo/setting-up-plan-build-dependencies-289276887.html).

So you would simply let `D` be triggered by both `B` and `C` and enter their plan keys to the enabled trigger condition *Only run Build if other Plans are currently passing*.